# Cannot Log to Database with NLog

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, logging, nlog

cannot log to database using "NLog".
I have tried the codes below.

**Program.cs**

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>().ConfigureLogging(logging => 
                    {
                        var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
                        logging.ClearProviders();
                        logging.AddNLog(string.Equals(env, "Production") ?
                                        "nlog.config" : "nlog.development.config");
                    });
                });
```

**nlog.development.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Info"
      internalLogFile="c:\temp\internal-nlog.txt">

  <!-- enable asp.net core layout renderers -->
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
  </extensions>

  <!-- the targets to write to -->
  <targets>
    <!-- write logs to file  -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName="nlog-all-${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />

    <!-- another file log, only own logs. Uses some ASP.NET core renderers -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="ownFile-web" fileName="nlog-own-${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}" />

    <target name="database" xsi:type="Database">
      <connectionString>Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Database=MyDB; integrated security=true;</connectionString>
      
      <commandText>
        insert into dbo.Log (
        MachineName, Logged, Level, Message,
        Logger, Callsite, Exception, ModuleType, EffectedUserId, EffectedUser,
        LoggerDetail
        ) values (
        @MachineName, @Logged, @Level, @Message,
        @Logger, @Callsite, @Exception, @ModuleType, @EffectedUserId, @EffectedUser,
        @LoggerDetail
        );
      </commandText>

      <parameter name="@MachineName" layout="${machinename}" />
      <parameter name="@Logged" layout="${date}" />
      <parameter name="@Level" layout="${level}" />
      <parameter name="@Message" layout="${message}" />
      <parameter name="@Logger" layout="${logger}" />
      <parameter name="@Callsite" layout="${callsite}" />
      <parameter name="@Exception" layout="${exception:tostring}" />
      <parameter name="@ModuleType" layout="${event-properties:moduleType}" />
      <parameter name="@EffectedUserId" layout="${event-properties:effectedUserId}" />
      <parameter name="@EffectedUser" layout="${event-properties:effectedUser}" />
      <parameter name="@LoggerDetail" layout="${event-properties:loggerDetail}" />
    </target>
    
  </targets>

  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
    <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="allfile" />

    <!--Skip non-critical Microsoft logs and so log only own logs-->
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxlevel="Error" final="true" /> <!-- BlackHole without writeTo -->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ownFile-web" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="database" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

The way I have tried to log,

```
var logEvent = new LogEventInfo(NLog.LogLevel.Error, loggerName, context.Exception.Message);
logEvent.Properties["effectedUserId"] = userId;
logEvent.Properties["effectedUser"] = userName;
logEvent.Properties["moduleType"] = moduleType;
logEvent.Properties["loggerDetail"] = serialized;            
logger.Log(logEvent);
```

I dont know what did I do wrong, actually I was looking NLog's .net core documentation to learn how to log to database.
I really got stuck in this... Please help. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Please check https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

Comment: Without error details, this is unsolvable. This could be anything, wrong column name, other column type, incorrect username, firewall etc.  There error details are in the internal log. (or enable throwExceptions).

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63168769/why-i-cant-save-logging-to-database-via-nlog ?

Comment: It turns out that my config file could not read the connectionstring section, and it got solved by when I set environment variable on web.config.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DatabaseLogging](https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/DatabaseLogging) to write ASP.NET Core logs to a database. Here is an example for [SQLite](https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/DatabaseLogging/blob/e3a7f0d85f252ee7c9cf2acc29ca3131cc28dcd8/src/DatabaseLogging.Tests/UnitTest1.cs#L18).

SQL Server:

```cs
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
serviceCollection.AddLogging((builder) =>
{
    builder.AddDatabase((options) =>
    {
        options.GetDatabaseContext = () =>
        {
            var context = new Context((builder) =>
            {
                builder.UseSqlServer("Server=(local);Database=Logging;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
            });

            return context;
        };
    });
});

var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
var loggerFactory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<TestClass>();
logger.LogInformation("Test {Hi}", 123);
```

[NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DatabaseLogging/0.2.0-alpha)